# I have this page that is breaking with an error Interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.4, php-7.2, unserialize

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here? I have this unserialize error too.

```
./var/report/c6b420e9dda8515f51d3e9cac8e8fb054e5bfdbc6c9a7dd6a2feb1faa50d0f68:1:{"0":"Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error","1":"#1 Magento\\Theme\\Controller\\Result\\MessagePlugin->getCookiesMessages() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-theme\/Controller\/Result\/MessagePlugin.php:167]\n#2 Magento\\Theme\\Controller\\Result\\MessagePlugin->getMessages() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-theme\/Controller\/Result\/MessagePlugin.php:95]\n#3 Magento\\Theme\\Controller\\Result\\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor#000000005e62cedd000000001393b868#, &Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor#000000005e62cedd000000001393b868#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000005e62cada000000001393b868#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000005e62cada000000001393b868#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000005e62cada000000001393b868#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#000000005e62cada000000001393b868#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000005e62cad8000000001393b868#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/floor-plans\/architect-series.html","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"c6b420e9dda8515f51d3e9cac8e8fb054e5bfdbc6c9a7dd6a2feb1faa50d0f68"}


./var/report/0bd204c08321061f4e7b4033fe5f40486e1ef4a70bc22fae0e212e736a1cb395:1:{"0":"Class Magento\\Store\\Model\\Website\\Interceptor does not exist","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Store\\Mo...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Definition\/Runtime.php:54]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Store\\Mo...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:48]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\Mo...', array('data' => array('website_id' => 1, 'code' => 'base', 'name' => 'Main Website', 'sort_order' => 0, 'default_group_id' => 1, 'is_default' => 1))) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Store\\M...', array('data' => array('website_id' => 1, 'code' => 'base', 'name' => 'Main Website', 'sort_order' => 0, 'default_group_id' => 1, 'is_default' => 1))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Store\/Model\/WebsiteFactory.php:43]\n#5 Magento\\Store\\Model\\WebsiteFactory->create(array('data' => array('website_id' => 1, 'code' => 'base', 'name' => 'Main Website', 'sort_order' => 0, 'default_group_id' => 1, 'is_default' => 1))) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/WebsiteRepository.php:210]\n#6 Magento\\Store\\Model\\WebsiteRepository->initDefaultWebsite() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/WebsiteRepository.php:156]\n#7 Magento\\Store\\Model\\WebsiteRepository->getDefault() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver\/Website.php:49]\n#8 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver\\Website->getAllowedStoreIds(NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoresData.php:65]\n#9 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoresData->getStoresData('website', NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver.php:138]\n#10 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getStoresData() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver.php:97]\n#11 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreManager.php:160]\n#12 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager->getStore(NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Store\/Model\/StoreManagerInterface\/Proxy.php:119]\n#13 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface\\Proxy->getStore(NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/Resolver\/Store.php:30]\n#14 Magento\\Store\\Model\\Resolver\\Store->getScope(NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Config\/ScopeCodeResolver.php:49]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Config.php:69]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config->getValue('admin\/url\/use_cu...', 'stores', NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Config\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\Interceptor->getValue('admin\/url\/use_cu...', 'store') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Area\/FrontNameResolver.php:123]\n#18 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Area\/FrontNameResolver.php:106]\n#19 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(true) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/AreaList.php:73]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName('floorplans') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:111]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000002bf1a8e60000000048cc42c6#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/floorplans\/architect-series\/montreal\/lake-bungalow\/lake-storage","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"0bd204c08321061f4e7b4033fe5f40486e1ef4a70bc22fae0e212e736a1cb395"}
```